# Is DI the only solution to Singleton and/or static objects?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I have been told that Singletons are hard to test.

- http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/
- http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-brittle-global-state-singletons/

I have been told that Static methods/objects are no good either.

- http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability/

So basically the only solution appears to be [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

But ... I really can't get used to DI, take this example:

In my framework I have a class that manages SQL. This class (and many other of my framework) uses a singleton Logger to logs message (and many other helpers).

With DI my code would turn to:

```
global $logger; //> consider i have been instanciated it at the start of my fw

$query = new PreparedQuery($logger);
$query->prepare() etc.
```

Now that doesn't seem too bad. But consider a page that needs many queries I believe it's pretty redundant to have to write everytime `$logger` in the constructor, especially if you consider if PreparedQuery needed many other dependencies in the constructor.

The only solution to *avoid* singleton that I have found **is to use a method (or just a simple function) in the main application that stores every references to this helper objects** (Service Locator/Container) but this doens't solve the problem of hiding the dependencies

So in your experience other than DI what is a good pattern to use?

### Solution:

For everyone interesetd the creator of PHPunit explains how to solve the Singleton problem (and how to solve static methods testing problem with PHP 5.3)

- (singleton) http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/882-Testing-Code-That-Uses-Singletons.html
- (static) http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/883-Stubbing-and-Mocking-Static-Methods.html

Pretty interesting read if you ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging is usually *the* example where static singletons are OK. You don't need to mock your logging anyway, do you?

Comment: @yes123 thats a pretty broad statement that im not sure i agree with, even if one guy posted about it... but im gonna have to agree with @OZ_ answer

Comment: @yes123: They aren't bad at all, but they are very very often misused, what leads to the low reputation. However, in some cases they are useful (and not bad ;))

Comment: It's true. Misko Hevery makes a distinction between Singletons with big S and singletons with small s. The latter is just to ensure one instance exists, the former is there to ensure you can call the one instance where needed. The former is bad.

Comment: @dynamic If you read this article by the same author: http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2008/08/root-cause-of-singletons.html you will notice how he mentions logging is one of the few cases where Singleton pattern is not a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Please, don't use `global`.
You need to pass $logger in constructors or pass Service Container instead (also known as Objects manager, Service Locator, Resources Manager).
Variant from Symfony framework http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html
You can create your own Objects Manager, and his methods should not be static.

Comment: So basically this is the only solution... Thanks for your reply but i knew it (read last paragraph of my question :))

Comment: one function will not be enough, and Service Container can be complicated (some methods will always return new, some will return existing instance, some will return clones, some methods will take arguments...).

Comment: In a project I am using an Objects Manager that's really a simple function and works perfectly. If you want I post the code

Comment: I believe, no reasons to arguing, just want to help. Hope that documentation page will be useful.

Comment: that's pretty helpful and i thank you... but In my framwork I doesn't have a controller where is wrapped in all my code.. so I can't use a `$this->container->get('object')` like sf does

Comment: You can pass instance of Objects Manager in any constructor. In constructor of model too.

Comment: Don't see any needs to use `global` anyway. In usual case, when you have controller (or, at least, front controller), Objects manager passed to controller through constructor. And when controller need some model, he takes it from Objects manager, which can pass himself to the Model too (just using $this) through constructor.

Comment: no man my framework is more a collections of classes/functions that helps doing some tasks. I don't have controllers as I stated before

Comment: in this exceptional case, I guess, static class will be much better, than `global` variable. But don't say anybody that it was my advice about static class :)

Comment: what about using just a function (like i am doing right now) ? Have a look at this code: http://codepad.org/jYQYt0kf that was what i mean with a simple function (note that can be easly modified to support prefixed argument like sf)

Comment: If this code works and you are satisfied - use it. Ideal code it's utopia, any code will be always not perfect and always will be ways for refactoring.

Comment: the more we talk the more I convince myself to use static. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024363/can-i-use-static-class-for-my-logger

Answer (score 3):

Well, in this case, I would build a [builder](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder) (or factory) instead. So your factory would inject the dependency for you.  That way you can also avoid your globals:

```
class PreparedQueryFactory {
    protected $logger = null;
    public function __construct($loggger) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    public function create() {
        return new PreparedQuery($this->logger);
    }
}
```

That way, you do once:

```
$factory = new PreparedQueryFactory($logger);
```

Then any time you need a new query, just call:

```
$query = $factory->create();
```

Now, this is a very simple example.  But you could add all sorts of complex logic if you need.  But the point is, by avoiding `new` in your code, you also avoid managing the dependencies.  So instead, you can pass the factory(ies) around as needed.

The benefit, is that all of this is 100% testable, since everything is injected everywhere (as opposed to using globals).

You can also use a registry (otherwise known as Service Container, or DI Container), but be sure you're injecting the registry in.

Comment: you know with this i still need to use global.. `global $factory`. Thus for each objects that uses helper (singleton) I will need to declare another object *Factory. (and if you have hundreds of objects in your framework that's not viable)

Comment: @yes: you don't need the global.  If you abstract this concept, everything will be injected.  And you don't need a factory for every class in your framework, you need a factory for every type of class that needs to be instantiated on the fly.  In fact, this is how a service container works, it just abstracts away the creation of the factory behind some configuration mechanics (XML or Yaml or annotations, etc).

Comment: @yes123 If you read some more articles of Misko Hevery you will see that he is also uses factories to create these kind of objects though DI is preferred where it applies.

Comment: @koen: I have searched a bit but found nothing could you post a link? @irc: I don't think I have got your last point. When you say "you need a factory for every type of class that needs to be instantiated on the fly" that's fine, but if you have many classes like that you will **have to** implements all other factory for taht

Comment: @yes123 http://misko.hevery.com/2009/03/30/collaborator-vs-the-factory/  or http://misko.hevery.com/2008/07/08/how-to-think-about-the-new-operator/#comment-570

Comment: Of course you can also question whether your design decision is correct: is a prepared query a service that needs other services? Misko Hevery also talks about object lifetimes and injection services. Should a prepared query be able to log itself?

Answer (score 1):

The above answers give you some ideas. I'll present another one: implement a plugin architecture. The logger the becomes a plugin which you can enable/disable/change whenever you want.

An simplified example:

```
class Logger implements Observer {
    public function notify($tellMeWhatHappened) {
         // oh really? let me do xyz
    }
}

class Query implements Observable {
    private $observers = array();

    public function addObserver(Observer $observer) {
        $this->observers[] = $observer;
    }

    public function foo() {
        // great code
        foreach ($this->observers as $observer) { $observer->notify('did not work'); }
    }
}
```

This removes the Logger away from the constructor. That is what I prefer if it is not essential for the functioning of the object.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding of Misko Hevery's talks on DI and the `new` operator, the problem is you haven't gone *far enough* in implementing DI.

What Hevery always says is you should not mix business logic with object construction. However, in the two lines of your example, the first (`$query = new PreparedQuery($logger);`) constructs an object, and then second (`$query->prepare(/* ... */);`) is business logic.

Clearly, the objective of that code is to prepare a query, and instead of worrying about how to build a `PreparedQuery`, it should just ask for one in the class constructor. Or if it needs to be able to produce lots of PreparedQueries, it should ask for a prototype (that it will clone whenever it needs a new one) or a factory object. The point is, the fact that the PreparedQuery has a logger is of no concern, and should be taken care of somewhere else.

The principle of "asking for what you need" in the constructor is easy to understand in principle, although I am still trying to work out for myself what it means in practise in various situations, and how to implement it all the way to the top (the "main method" or equivalent). However, I think this principle speaks to the general problem you're having. That `new` operator should not be where it is in the first place.