# Static methods: are they still bad considering PHP 5.3 late static binding?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection, singleton

If you search on the reasons why static methods are bad the first thing you find it is because you can't override it when you are unit testing.

So is this still true considering in PHP 5.3 you can do whatever you want with the introduction of `static::`?

### Add:

http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/883-Stubbing-and-Mocking-Static-Methods.html

Note he explains even how to use singleton without any testing problem:

- http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/882-Testing-Code-That-Uses-Singletons.html

Comment: *(hint)* It's called **Object** Oriented Programming for a reason. In case you haven't read it yet: http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0103_static_considered_harmful.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have a static member function, it could usually be a free function. The usual reaction is then that the coder has opted for a static member function only because of the myth that "everything must be in an object".

That's why people discourage them.

And, because it's not a very convincing argument, those people pointed to unit testing instead. Not sure what they'll do now.

Comment: take for example the Logger class.. it can be easly all static in a framework

Comment: @yes123: At which point one asks why you have a class for it in the first place. (The practical answer is, of course, that PHP's namespace syntax is new and horrid.. but that's not really the point.)

Comment: @yes123 Logger should be an interface which you then implement (eg FlatFileLogger).

Comment: @Tomalak: Every static class has an own scope to keep its state (like every common class too). If you use functions only, you must use globals.

Comment: @KingCrunch: Have you heard of namespaces? And/or are you part of the "globals are bad lol mmmkay" crowd?

Comment: @KingCrunch: Ah, so it seems. Still, you could use `static` variables inside your functions inside your namespace, but I agree that that's a bit nasty. Certainly for other languages a "static class" is oft a bad idea, but perhaps that's not so much the case in PHP.

Comment: @Tomalak: OK, with this statement I agree :)

Comment: @KingCrush: A happy ending :)

Answer (score 10):

Static methods aren't bad in themselves. Sometimes certain operations don't make sense to require a particular object to do. For example, a function like square root would make more sense being static.

```
Math::sqrRoot(5);
```

rather than having to instantiate a Math 'object' and then call the function.

```
$math = new Math();
$result = $math->sqrRoot(5);
```

Comment: and you can now, so what's the problem?

Comment: I'm interested in how LSB helps with dependency injection - I understand that if a method requires an object that adheres to an interface as one of its parameters, I can substitute any object that fulfils that interface (including test objects) - but I still don't see how you can make that substitution for statically called methods, since you have to specify the name of the class you are calling the static method on. Workarounds such as using call_user_func() existed pre-LSB. Can you shed some light on this for me?

Comment: I believe you can use variables for the class name in PHP 5.3, e.g. `$classname::method();`

Comment: I don't see the point in using classes for something like `Math` at all. Use a namespace, if anything.

Comment: See my answer for a reason as to why static methods can be bad in unit testing.

Answer (score 6):

More difficult to test is a reason but not the only one. Static methods provide global access, and global access is bad.

Of course, you'll find that there's another global access to objects and that's creating one with 'new'. Objects have to be created somewhere so we can't eliminate that (though minimizing it is a good idea). Static methods as global access to a class is bad, unless it is there to replace 'new' through higher level programming:

```
$user = new User();
$user->setPointsTo(100);

// vs

$user = User::with100StartingPoints();
```

In this case I created code that is more readable while not misusing global access (the 'new' needed to be called anyway).

Edit: Let me give you an example in the way static methods 'can' be the death of testability (note how in the example above you don't even need to mock the static method but can easily test the new and static method produces the same result). Let's use your logger example:

```
class Logger {
    public static function log($text) { // etc }
}

class AccessControl {
    public function isAllowed(User $user, $action) {
      // do stuff, determine if $allowed
      if (!$allowed) {
          Logger::log('user X was not allowed to do Y');
      }
      // do stuff
    }
}
```

There is no way we can test this method cleanly because of the global call to Logger::log. It will depend on the correct working of the Logger class.

Comment: @yes123 You can test static methods but it's difficult to test code calling the static method.