# What pattern to choose for php module?

Tags: php, design-patterns, module

I'd like to have a little php module. This module would have methods that are pure functions. So, this is just a collection of functions. All function get some arguments and return result depending only on input parameters.

I have some suggestions:

**1. Static class**

PHP hasn't real static class, so I just make a class with all static methods:

```
class Some_Module
{
    static public function sum($a, $b, $c)
    {
        return $a+$b+$c;
    }

    static public function method2($a, $b)
    {
         return $a-$b+5;
    }
}
```

It's very easy to use such modules:

```
$x = Some_module::sum(1,2,3);
```

But, I've heard (there are lots of topics on SO), that static is a bad practice.

**2. Singleton**

It's not so easy to use:

```
// we should not to forget to get instance
$module_instance = new Some_module;
$x = $module_instance->sum(1,2,3);
```

Inconvenience is in that fact, that we should initialize this module now.
Also, there is a huge amount of topics on SO, where is explained why Singleton are not useful in PHP, so it's a bad practice too.

What pattern to use for such a module?

Comment: It's foremost a bad practice to take advise from hearsay. -- Your example is too abstract to recommend one implementation over the other. Clearly throwing in-out functions into an object isn't very sensible however. While they should be plain functions, static classes are an accepted workaround for functionality grouping (it's nothing more). Particularly if you can't stand the namespace syntax alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this discussion will help in your decision [Static methods: are they still bad considering PHP 5.3 late static binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035822/static-methods-are-they-still-bad-considering-php-5-3-late-static-binding)

Personally, it depends on the context. To store a bunch of misc. helper methods, more likely I'll use it as a global and namespace it. In storing a limited amount of methods of a particular category that have no need to be instantiated, a static class might be a good option. Just be aware for unit testing purposes, many classes using static methods in the wrong context like `cool::method` is going to be hell.

```
// keep it abstract to prevent it from being instantiated
abstract class Foo {
   // cannot be altered if inherited, although limitation still exists
   final public static function bar() {
      echo 'test';
   }
}

Foo::bar();
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple, use a class but don't make the methods static.  Sure, that means you'll use one extra line to instantiate it, it's not a big deal.  You'll be able to extend the class properly and mock it for tests as well.